# How do I change the fonts used in a github pages theme?

Tags: github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm using the [primer](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer#usage) theme from github pages, and would like to change all the fonts in the theme.

I've tried to follow the instructions provided in other posts and the theme's [page](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer#usage), i.e., to create an `assets/css/style.scss` file and add:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

However, I don't see any changes in the font used on my github page. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: This approach works for me for the Slate theme. My `style.scss` looks just like the one in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
.markdown-body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@import "../../assets/css/styles.scss";` inside `primer/_sass/primer-base/index.scss`

Comment: I don't have such a file on my repo (my earlier link is the github theme's repo). Are u suggesting to create another file `_sass/primer-base/index.scss` in my repo with an additional statement `@import "../../assets/css/style.scss"` inside (with previous import statements also copied over)? I've tried out ur suggestion but had no success with it.